# SQL Insert into XML datatype column truncates the characters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, insert

I have a XML datatype column in table.

When I try to insert lengthy encrypted string (ex: "7L1dj23bdRz2nAD5D4QeguRB") with 3251148 characters into it, it just truncates and stores only a partial string with the first 2097154 characters, instead of full string.

What would cause these issue? Any Ideas?

Comment: SSMS had a ~2mb limit for displaying XML in the grid, are you hitting that? (Increase it in tools > options) or select datalength(col) to see if its what you expect.

Comment: @AlexK. I have problem in Insert, string is almost 6.502296MB in size

Comment: @YogeshSharma its just simple insert

Comment: @sandeep question is: how do you know it's truncated? how do you check?

Comment: I was wrong, it was storing in DB has is, but in select query it used to get trimmed, because of settings.